# Splitting comma separated strings in MYSQL for dynamic drop down list

Tags: php, mysql, csv

Right now I am having trouble with splitting up entries in my ethnicity column that contain entries that are separated by commas for example take a look at my
[Ethnicity table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x9gYI.png)

I want to be able to split up these strings into individual strings so they can all be their own entries (ex: asian, chinese, catina would all be seperate entries). I don't want to make any changes to my existing table I just want to be able to seperate these strings because I am using php to create a dynamic drop down list based on what is stored in this ethnicity column:

```
    <h3>*Category</h3> 
   <select name="category" multiple>
   <?php
    $conn = mysqli_connect(db, root, pass, table);
    // Check connection
    if (!$conn) {
      die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
    }
      $result = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT DISTINCT restaurant_id, ethnicity FROM ethnicity");
      while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
              unset($restaurantID, $ethnicity);
              $restaurantID = $row['restaurant_id'];
              $ethnicity = $row['ethnicity'];
              echo '<option value="'.$ethnicity.'">'.$ethnicity.'</option>';
  }

  ?>
  </select>
```

Right now the drop down list is including the [comma separated strings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VgCxs.png) and I just want it to be able to display the distinct ethnicities individually. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I'd start buy doing the query above and [exploding](http://php.net/explode) all the ethnicities into a new array and then printing them out:

(I haven't tested syntax just used notepad, hopefully you get the idea though.)

```
<h3>*Category</h3> 

<?php
 $conn = mysqli_connect(db,root,pass,table);
 // Check connection
 if (!$conn) {
   die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
 }

 $ethnicity_array = [];

 $result = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT DISTINCT restaurant_id, ethnicity FROM ethnicity");
 while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
 {
    unset($restaurantID, $ethnicity);
    $restaurantID = $row['restaurant_id'];
    $ethnicity = $row['ethnicity'];

    $split_ethnicity = explode("," $ethnicity);
    foreach ($split_ethnicity as $value)
    {
        if (!in_array($value, $ethnicity_array))
            $ethnicity_array[] = $value;
    }
}

?>

<select name="category" multiple>
  <?php
    foreach ($ethnicity_array as $ethnicity)
    {
      echo '<option value="'.$ethnicity.'">'.$ethnicity.'</option>';
    }
  ?>
</select>
```

Comment: where you use $split_ethnicity after exploding it.

Comment: Oopsy, supposed to be in the foreach typo :P, fixed.

Comment: It doesn't seem as if you are appending anything to the ethnicity_array :/

Comment: @Kiki, sorry i missed out something on the in_array line, try now. (I'm at work and just using a normal text editor so, mistakes happen :()

Comment: I see your logic for this but for some reason the drop down is not even showing up anymore. Could be a syntax problem?

Comment: Found it! It wa a syntax problem, your forgot a comma when you were defining $split_ethnicity.  However the in_array function isn't working, I'm getting individual values for the drop down list but they are getting repeated